# Checking host reachability on windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, network-programming, ping

How can I check in batch-file if host is reachable or not? The problem is that `ping` returns 0 not only on success, but also on `Destination host unreachable` error:

```
C:\>ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 3ms

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0

C:\>ping 192.168.1.105 -n 1

Pinging 192.168.1.105 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.102: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.105:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Is there any way to do it with `ping` or any other build-in-Windows tool? I would prefer not to install anything if that's possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 -n 1 | FIND /I "Reply from "
```

Then you can check errorlevel

Edit: To accommodate "Destination host unreachable error you could do this:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 -n 1 | FIND /I /V "unreachable" | FIND /I "Reply from "
```

Comment: nice one, although had to find "TTL" rather than "Reply from ", since "Destination host unreachable" also has "Reply from " within ;)

Comment: What about `Reply from 192.168.1.102: Destination host unreachable.` ?

Comment: LOL - that works. Although I too prefer the `TTL=` method. (it's shorter and language independent)

Answer (score 7):

Next code snippet should work:

```
set "_ip=localhost"
set "_ip=192.168.1.1"
ping %_ip% -n 1 -4 | find /i "TTL=">nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ping %_ip% failure
) else ( 
    echo ping %_ip% success
)
```

- `-4` to force using IPv4 (as e.g. ping `localhost` replies IPv6 with no `TTL=` output)
- `| find /i "TTL="` as `find` command raises `errorlevel` well
- `>nul` to suppress undesired output

Answer (score 1):

I think tracert is what you need.Sets errorlevel on 1 if cant find the host.And should use the same port as ping.`-h 2` is to reduce wait time ,as the complete route is not needed.

```
tracert -h 2 somehost.com >nul 2>nul && (
  echo reachable host
) || (
  echo unreachable host
)
```

**EDIT**: to print correct errorlevel in the brackets you need delayed expansion.Here's more advanced example :

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo checking google.com
tracert -h 1 google.com >nul 2>nul && (
  echo reachable host
  echo !errorlevel!
  rem prevent execution of negative condition
  color 22
) || (
  echo unreachable host 
  echo !errorlevel!
)


echo checking asdasdjjakskwkdhasdasd
tracert -h 1 asdasdjjakskwkdhasdasd >nul 2>nul && (
  echo reachable host#
  echo !errorlevel!
   rem prevent execution of negative condition
   color
) || (
  echo unreachable host#
  echo !errorlevel!
)
```

Comment: @burtek - if its reachable and not reachable?

Comment: @burtek - try not to print the errorlevel in the brackets , but after them.Or execute these on two lines : `tracert nosuchhost`  and `echo %errorlevel%`

Comment: Ok, so it works perfectly for domains, but does not work for ip addresses. For `tracert nosuchhost` errorlevel is 1, for `tracert google.pl` it's 0, but both for existing and not existing ip addresses I get errorlevel 0. Also, running `tracert` with not existing ip address results in http://pastebin.com/DieTCw15

Comment: @burtek - didn't test it with ip addresses...WIll check it.